# msSaveBlob does not return the full image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I am trying to implement a download button for Internet Explorer users that will let them download a png file being displayed on a page.

The image is provided as a Data URL and displays normally on the page.

However, when the image is downloaded on Internet Explorer using the following code, **only the upper half of the image** gets downloaded.

I know the problem does not come from `dataURLtoBlob()` because reading the blob as a Data Url returns exactly the same original data.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? Thanks a lot for the help.

```
downloadButton.onclick = function () {

    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

        var filename = "image.png";
        var data = $('#qrCode').attr("href");
        var blob = dataURLtoBlob(data);

        console.log(data);

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 

        reader.onload = function() {
            console.log(reader.result); 
        };

        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
}

function dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl) {

    var arr = dataUrl.split(',');
    var mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    var byteString = atob(arr[1]);
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mime });
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? I think it might be the issue with the image as I tried with your code and it can download well in IE 11. There might be some issue with the data uri, you could use another image to try. I used an online image to data URI converter to get the data URI code, then used your code to convert to blob and download, it can download the full image. You could also try this way.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou. The IE console does not show any kind of error. 

As you suggest, the issue could possibly come from the data itself (I am generating Qr Codes using a library called QRCoder). 

However, I do not understand how IE can displays the image fine with an img tag (such as `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...>`) or successfully download the image with a right click, but fails to download the full image using the blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue by using an intermediate canvas.

```
        var ieCanvas = document.getElementById("ieCanvas");
        var ctx = ieCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("qrCodeImg");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var filename = "download.png";
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(ieCanvas.msToBlob(), filename);
```

To summarise:

- QR Code PNG -> Blob -> msSaveBlob = **Half of the image**
- QR Code PNG -> Canvas -> Blob -> msSaveBlob = **Full image**